# A Mix of Puzzles

Tags: mathematics, word, enigmatic-puzzle, knowledge

> Weapon of the sea, undented, times x or y minus the first, reversed.
>
> 3-4 triangle complete.
>
> A bucky lemur nun.
>
> Shakespearean poem less nonagon's sides.
>
> Krypton minus vanadium. (omg i messed this up too, sorry)
>
> In, at, of or pi.
>
> Flags in tic-tac-toe position 3 and 8.
>
> 10010 (my b, messed this up)
>
> Palindromic animals slammed in a net plus backwards epsilon.
>
> Neutrons in carbon isotope with 20-minute half-life.
>
> Knights and queens on a starting chessboard.
>
> $(2.5x^3-28x^2+163x-6374)'''$
>
> rvtugrra.

Hint 1:

> In mathematics, x and y are often used to refer to a certain four-letter word.

Comment: +1 for Krypton!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Weapon of the sea, undented, times x or y minus the first, reversed.

> A weapon of the sea is a trident, undented gives tri which means 3. x and y refer to an axis, minus the first letter xis then reversed is six. 3x6 =18.

3-4 triangle complete.

> As found by @Omega Krypton 3,4,**5** triangle by Pythagorean theorem.

A bucky lemur nun.

> Anagram for 'an unlucky number' which is 13.

Shakespearean poem less nonagon's sides.

> As stated by @AHKieran a sonnet has 14 lines and a nonagon has 9 sides therefore 14-9=5.

Krypton minus vanadium.

> Krypton's atomic number is 36, Vanadium's is 23, so 36-23 = 13

In, at, of or pi.

> Best guess for now is first two digits of pi since each word is two letters which gives 3 and 1. 3 -1 is 2 possibly or 3+1 is 4? Likely gives a two.

Flags in tic-tac-toe position 3 and 8.

> As found by @JR_M using semaphore flags you get 5.

10010.

> is 18 in binary.

Palindromic animals slammed in a net plus backwards epsilon.

> A palindromic animal is a ewe, an epsilon backwards looks like a 3. Not sure from here with this one. net backward is ten, 10+3 gives 13.

Neutrons in carbon isotope with 20-minute half-life.

> Carbon-11 has a 20 minute life and has 5 neutrons.

Knights and queens on a starting chessboard.

> there are 6 (4 knights and 2 queens on a chessboard to begin). Also possible it is referring to the rank or file of there positions.

$(2.5x^3 - 28x^2 +163x-6374)'''$

> The 3 apostrophes indicate third derivative of the equation which is 15.

rvtugrra.

> rot13 on it gives eighteen.

Final Answer:

> If you take all the numbers: 18-5-13-5-13-*-5-13-*-5-6-15-18 and translate using a1z26 you get REMEM_ER_EFOR. If I had to guess the 6th letters is a B and then the 9th letter is either a B or an M. If they are both Bs it is a misspelling of remember before, if the second letter is an m it gives remember me for... which is part of a lyric in fall out boy's song, centuries.

Comment: (rot13) vs v erzrzore pbeerpgyl, n fbaarg unf sbhegrra yvarf

Comment: @AHKieran lbh qb vaqrrq erzrzore pbeerpgyl

Comment: (Also, I messed up the binary, it's fixed now.)

Comment: Yep, (rot 13) praghevrf is the answer.

Answer (score 4):

Very Partial Answer:

3-4 triangle:

> 5 of course! (Pythagoras Theorem)

Nickel minus Vanadium:

> 5 too! (Atomic number difference, see periodic table)

Answer (score 4):

Partial Answer:

Flags in tic-tac-toe position 3 and 8.

> If you are using semaphore flags, then this would be **5** because flags in tic-tac-toe position 3 and 8 represent the number 5.

Answer (score 4):

Others can use this but:

> x or y are axes/axis, minus the first = xis, reversed = six.
>  As already explained, weapon of sea is trident, indented is tri = 3.
>  $3 \cdot 6 = 18$